# Windows Server scheduled task (R script) fails - log not informative

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, windows-server

I'm trying to schedule an R script to run weekly via Windows Server 2008 task scheduler.

Originally I set up the task via `taskscheduleR` like so:

```
library(taskscheduleR)
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "twitter_scrape",
                     rscript = "T:\\HackR\\Folder\\web_sna\\code\\twitter_scheduled.R",
                     startdate = format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y"),
                     schedule = "WEEKLY")
```

The task failed with an error code of `0xc000013a`. When clicking the task's Properties then viewing the History tab, the events indicate that it completed successfully, however it actually did not, as the return status code implies.

Following various troubleshooting material I found online, I tried changing several options, including

- Enabling "run whether user is logged on or not" in combination with "run with highest privileges"
- Adding the script's parent directory to the optional "Start in" field

The only effect of those options on the outcome was changing the error code (Last Return Result) to 0x1.

The external log file created by the task reads as follows:

> ```
> trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/twitteR_1.1.9.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 446306 bytes (435 KB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 435 KB
>
> package 'twitteR' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>   F:\temp\RtmpasZDYO\downloaded_packages
>
> twitteR installed
> ^C
> ```

Of course, the script runs fine when run manually.